# Symfony 5 composer update fails with security-checker

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

When I do `composer update`, I have these script that are played at the end:

```
Executing script cache:clear [OK]
Executing script assets:install --symlink --relative public [OK]
Executing script security-checker security:check [KO]
 [KO]
Script security-checker security:check returned with error code 1
!!                                                              
!!    The web service failed for an unknown reason (HTTP 403).  
!!                                                              
!!  
Script @auto-scripts was called via post-install-cmd
```

I only have the security bundle that is installed `"symfony/security-bundle": "5.3.*"`, when I use this command it works fine:

- `symfony security:check`

But the compose update seems to use the old

- `php bin/console security:check`

Why is that ?

My composer.json

```
{
    "type": "project",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "require": {
        "behat/mink-goutte-driver": "^1.2",
        "composer/package-versions-deprecated": "1.11.99.2",
        "datadog/php-datadogstatsd": "^1.5",
        "doctrine/annotations": "^1.0",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^2.4",
        "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^3.1",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.9",
        "jms/serializer-bundle": "^3.10",
        "okvpn/datadog-symfony": "^0.3.1",
        "phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock": "^5.2",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^6.1",
        "symfony/apache-pack": "^1.0",
        "symfony/asset": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/console": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/dotenv": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/expression-language": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/flex": "^1.3.1",
        "symfony/form": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/http-client": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/intl": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/mailer": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/mime": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.1",
        "symfony/notifier": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/process": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/property-access": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/property-info": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/proxy-manager-bridge": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/runtime": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/security-bundle": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/sendinblue-mailer": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/serializer": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/stopwatch": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/string": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/templating": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/translation": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/twig-bundle": "^5.3",
        "symfony/validator": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/web-link": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/yaml": "5.3.*",
        "symfonycasts/reset-password-bundle": "^1.9",
        "twig/extra-bundle": "^3.3",
        "twig/intl-extra": "^3.3",
        "twig/twig": "^2.12|^3.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "behat/behat": "^3.8",
        "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "^3.4",
        "friends-of-behat/mink-browserkit-driver": "^1.5",
        "friends-of-behat/mink-extension": "^2.5",
        "friends-of-behat/symfony-extension": "^2.2",
        "phpstan/extension-installer": "^1.1",
        "phpstan/phpstan-doctrine": "^0.12.44",
        "phpstan/phpstan-symfony": "^0.12.41",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5",
        "symfony/browser-kit": "^5.3",
        "symfony/css-selector": "^5.3",
        "symfony/debug-bundle": "^5.3",
        "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.0",
        "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^5.3",
        "symfony/var-dumper": "^5.3",
        "symfony/web-profiler-bundle": "^5.3"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": {
            "*": "dist"
        },
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "replace": {
        "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php72": "*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "auto-scripts": {
            "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
            "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
        },
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "conflict": {
        "symfony/symfony": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "allow-contrib": false,
            "require": "5.3.*"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share more details, like the configuration for this script from your composer.json

Comment: Just added my composer.json

Answer (score 0):

You most likely have something like this in your `composer.json`:

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "auto-scripts": {
      "security-checker security:check": "script"
    }
  }
}
```

Replace the `"security-checker security:check": "script"` with `"symfony check:security": "script"`:

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "auto-scripts": {
      "symfony check:security": "script"
    }
  }
}
```

That is assuming the `symfony` binary is in your PATH, if it's not specify a full path to the binary (for example `"/home/my-username/symfony check:security": "script"`).

Comment: I don't actually, only this:
`"scripts": {"auto-scripts": {"cache:clear": "symfony-cmd", "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"}, "post-install-cmd": ["@auto-scripts"], "post-update-cmd": ["@auto-scripts"]},`

Comment: Well, you can see from the output that `post-install-cmd` is called, which triggers `auto-scripts` which triggers `security-checker security:check`. Are you sure you're showing us the correct `composer.json`? Check from which directory the command is ran and if there isn't any `composer.json` in that directory.

Comment: I work with symfony since a long time and never had this issue (even when I initially set up this project), so I don't really understand why. This is the only composer.json available in the project and im' sure i'm executing the `composer update` form the right directory.

Comment: Can you put the code on GitHub? I don't think any actual source code is necessary so the `src` directory can be empty (or maybe just with the `Kernel` class).

Comment: Well, I deleted my *composer.phar*, my *composer.lock*, my vendors folder, clean rm -rf the cache, flushed my cache for composer packages, and re-installed everything all back, and it worked...